# MASM can automate jump-extending with errors?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, x86-16

The follow page in masm states the following:
If a source file 8086-80286 program contains a conditional jump outside the range of -128 to +127 bytes, the assembler emits a level 3 warning and generates 2 instructions (including a unconditional jump) that are the equivalent of the desired instruction. This behavior can be enabled and disabled the the  **OPTION LJMP** and **OPTION NOLJMP** directives.

The following code does not do what is stated above:

```
.8086
OPTION LJMP
.model tiny
.data
mydata db ?
.code
Label1: xor ax,ax
inc ax
db 128 dup (?)
jz Label1
jmp Label1
end
```

The code created is as follows:

```
                .8086
                OPTION LJMP
                .model tiny
 0000           .data
                ;Dseg segment byte public
 0000 00            mydata db ?
                ;Dseg ends
                ;assume ds:Dseg
                ;Cseg segment byte public
 0000               .code
 0000  33 C0    Label1:  xor ax,ax
 0002  40                inc ax
 0003  0080 [            dw 128 dup(?)
        0000
       ]
 0103  75 03 E9 FEF8     jz  label1
 0108  E9 FEF5           jmp Label1
                ;Cseg ends
                end
```

No errors are generated. I expected an error because I specifically selected 
.8086 for the code assembled. Note that the .386 form of the conditional jump
is created. It creates the exact same code if a .8086 thru .286 is used.  Because of this I believe that no error is created. I have not been able to have the assembler generate any error messages for conditional jumps if SHORT is not in the instruction. Is this a bug??? How do I get an example of the code needed for this error to occur?

Comment: You have a typo: `JLMP` vs `LJMP`

Comment: Please fix the remaining formatting yourself.

Comment: The assembler is clearly generating 32-bit code, as evidenced by the operand size prefixes on the instructions that refer to ax.  So it appears that the .8086 directive is either ignored or overridden. How did you invoke the assembler?

Comment: The first line of the assembly listing shows that you're actually assembling code that uses the `.386` directive and not `.8086`.  You may be forgetting to save your changes before assembling the file or accidentally assembling a different file than the file you're editing.

Comment: What MASM version are you using? Version 10.0 from 2010 dropped 16-bit support and also the .8086 directive, I don't know if it would give an error about the unknown directive. Of course the documentation you are quoting refers to 16-bit stuff, but I don't know if you are using a matching version of the documentation, and it might be possible that this part just hasn't been removed.

Comment: Thanks everybody for the comments. I pasted the wrong listing file. I have now pasted the correct listing file. I am using a older version of masm version 6.14.8444. It is suppose to support both versions. Is this a know bug that was fixed in later versions?

Comment: Your updated assembly listing shows that the assembler generated two 8086 instructions for the `jz  label1` line. It's not generating a '386 conditional jump, so there doesn't appear to be any bug.

Comment: @idspispopd While modern versions of MASM (eg. 14.15.26730.0 from Visual Studio 2017) don't support the .8086 directive, they still support 16-bit code.

Comment: According to my information that I have from Microsoft's masm the instruction for a conditional jump is a 2 byte instruction for microprocessors 80286 and below. For microprocessors 80386 and above the conditional jumps are 5 bytes long. Since I am not specificing SHORT and the jump is longer than 128 bytes I would expected to get a error. What am I overlooking?

Comment: OK, NOW I see what I am overlooking. There are 2 instructions for the jump. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I noticed that my version of masm does not give me any warning when the conditional jump instruction is "jump extended". Is there a way to have the assembler give me a warning so that I can modify my code with the changes?